# how to log the custom object record from inserted from vf page if it has the same values with no error message

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a controller class

```
public class wholeunitclass {

// Defining Variables.
public Case_Action__c applicant;
public List<Case_Action__c> results {get;set;}
public List<Case_Action__c> ServiceRef {get;set;}
public List<Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c> lowesportal = new List<Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c>();
public List<Account> AccList {get;set;}
public string ShowMsg {get;set;}
public string Showmsg1 {get;set;}

public wholeunitclass(){
}

// Getting Value of Serial Number.
public String serialNum{
    get;
    set{
       serialNum=value;
    }
}

 // Getting Value of Store Number.
 public String storeNum{
    get;
    set{
       storeNum=value;
    }
 }


public List<string> TrimLeadZero(string value_by_user){
string check_value=null;
check_value= value_by_user;
List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();
    for(integer i=0;i<3;i++){
    if(check_value.startsWith('0') && check_value.length() > 1 && check_value.length() < =6 ){
     check_value= check_value.substring(1);
     stringlist.add(check_value);
 }
 else{
      stringlist.add(value_by_user);
 }
}      
return stringlist;
}

// Start Method
public PageReference getSerial(){
     results=new List<Case_Action__c>();

     // Show Error if Store Number or Serial Number is Blank.
     if(storeNum=='' || serialNum==''){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Fields cannot be blank'));
        return null;
      }
    else{
        // Query to Check Validation of Store Number
        List<string> stringlist = TrimLeadZero(storeNum);
        system.debug(stringlist);

        AccList=[select id,Customer_Branch__c from Account where Customer_Branch__c IN :stringList  and Parent.Name = 'LOWE\'S COMPANIES, INC.'];
            if(AccList.size() > 0 ){
                //Modified ON: 07/13/2016
                //fetching of number of days from custom settings
                Lowes_Water_Heater_Days_Check__c lwhdc = Lowes_Water_Heater_Days_Check__c.getValues('Date');
                Decimal numberofdays =  lwhdc.Number_of_Days__c;

                //Query to check Validation of Serial Number
                // Query to get data related to Case Action Record.
                results=[select id, name, Reference_Number__c,Replacement_Type__c, CreatedDate,Case__r.Asset.Name,Case__r.Asset.id,
                        Case__r.Asset.Product2.Customer_SKU__c, Case__r.Asset.Product2.ProductCode, Case__r.Asset.Product2.Tank_Capacity_Gallons__c, Case__r.Asset.Product2.Tank_Warranty__c
                        from Case_Action__c Where Replacement_Type__c = 'Lowe\'s Return' and Case__r.Asset.Name = :serialNum and RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Whole_Unit_Replacement'  and CreatedDate >= :Date.Today().addDays(Integer.valueof(-numberofdays))
                        Order By CreatedDate DESC Limit 1];

                        system.debug(results);
                        system.debug(storeNum);
                        system.debug(serialNum);

                        if(results ==null || results.size() == 0){
                           // Redirect to Assistance Page if Serial Number is Invalid.
                            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/serialNumAssistance');
                            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
                            return pageRef;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            if(results.size() > 1)
                            {
                            return null;
                            }
                        }

                 List<Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c> lowesportal1 = [select id,name,Store_Number__c,Serial_Number__r.name from Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c WHERE CreatedDate = today and Store_Number__c = :storeNum and Serial_Number__r.name =:serialNum ];
                        system.debug(lowesportal1);

                        for(Integer i=0;i < lowesportal1.size();i++)
                        if(lowesportal1[i].Store_Number__c == storeNum && lowesportal1[i].Serial_Number__r.name == serialNum){
                         Showmsg1 = 'This authorization was previously used by your store on ' + results[0].CreatedDate + '. An authorization is only valid for one RTM transaction.';
                        }


                        if(results[0].Case__r.Asset.Product2.Tank_Capacity_Gallons__c == 80 || results[0].Case__r.Asset.Product2.Tank_Warranty__c == '999 Months'){
                            ShowMsg = 'The item being returned is no longer available and has been permanently removed from the system. Below is the item number for the best eqvivalent replacement unit.' + '<br/><br/>' + 'Use the below information to process the return and RTM to vendor.';
                        }

                        else{
                            ShowMsg = 'Use the below information to process the return and RTM to vendor';
                        }


                        // Insert Search Results into Custom Object Lowes Portal Transaction.


                       for(Integer i=0;i < lowesportal.size();i++)
                       if(lowesportal[i].Serial_Number__c == results[0].Case__r.Asset.id)

                        lowesportal.add(New Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c(Authorization_Number__c = results[0].id,
                                                               Serial_Number__c = results[0].Case__r.Asset.id,
                                                               Account__c = AccList[0].id));
                        insert lowesportal;

                         system.debug(lowesportal);

        }


}
```

The first time that a store enters a valid store number and serial number, the existing page will

display with no changes. This will log the first Lowes Portal Transaction for that authorization.

i have tried this code to modify like this

```
     if(lowesportal.size == 0 && lowesportal == null){
   lowesportal.add(New Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c(Authorization_Number__c = results[0].id,Serial_Number__c = results[0].Case__r.Asset.id,Account__c = AccList[0].id));
insert lowesportal;

else{
return null;
}
```

but its not working and i am stuck in this code...!! please help me.

Comment: remove unnecessary code and clearly mention the issue with an example, in the case people can understand what your are looking for

Comment: In this whenever i am entering serial number and store number there is a object created, if i enter same serial and store number again and again so i want to log the object if i enter the same value again the record will not create.how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I could understand correctly, storeNum and Serial Number can come more than once.

In that case, you will insert the record for the first time. Next time onward record will not create.

Declare a map in the declarations section.

```
Map<String, Integer> mapLowesportal = new Map<String, Integer>();
```

Add following check in `getSerial()` method.

In the map, add SerialNumber and StoreNum as key and `i` as a value. And before adding to the `lowesportal` list check if those values already exist in the map.

*check attributes properly, I have shown you as an example*

```
for(Integer i=0;i < lowesportal1.size();i++)
{
   if(lowesportal1[i].Serial_Number__c == results[0].Case__r.Asset.id)
   {
       if(!mapLowesportal.containsKey(lowesportal1[i].Serial_Number__c + '-' + storeNum))
       {
           lowesportal.add(New Lowes_Portal_Transaction__c(Authorization_Number__c = results[0].id,
                                       Serial_Number__c = results[0].Case__r.Asset.id,
                                       Account__c = AccList[0].id));
            mapLowesportal.put(lowesportal1[i].Serial_Number__c + '-' + storeNum, i);   
       }                       
   }
}
insert lowesportal;
system.debug(lowesportal);
```

Otherwise,

> Create a text field and make that field a unique
>
> Update that text field value with serialNumber - storeNumber combination

Comment: on system.debug() i am getting null values

Comment: In your code there is an issue with `lowesportal` variable. check the for loop, which variable you will use `lowesportal` or `lowesportal1`?

Comment: in actual lowesportal is a list as u can see ,so in starting it will null so is it possible i will add the value in that. lowesportal1 is a different variable

Comment: which list you will loop through that is up to you. the list should have values otherwise it will not insert

Comment: check my updated ans. I think it will be `lowesportal1` in the for loop

Comment: it still getting null.
and what is the meaning of this line
if(!mapLowesportal.containsKey(lowesportal1[i].Serial_Number__c + '-' + storeNum))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59948/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-sonam-mittal).